# AJAX: What happens to a callback response after page redirect?

Tags: ajax

When we use ajax request with PHP, the server side usually end with:

```
exit( json_encode(somedata) )
```

and use this response data in client side but
what happen when the server side redirect to another page? What happen to ajax callback method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After redirecting to a different page, all Javascript callback events are unregistered, so the AJAX callback is not being fired anywhere. It's forever lost in the vastness of the cybernetic world.

[image]

Comment: If so, I want to show error to user and if there is no error it is redirected to another page. Is it ok?

Comment: You want to redirect only on the AJAX success?

Comment: Yes, I use exit(json_encode(["error_msg", "error"])) when the request has some error. If not 
redirect to another page.

Comment: Good! I'm glad for you. Any other questions?

Comment: Sorry man. It does not work well. Redirect with ajax request only print page source and does not go to another page. But it is ok. I will use js for redirection. Thanks anyway.